# Pyside progressbar cannot refresh

Tags: pyqt, pyside

This is the sample code using Pyside, to show a progressbar on button click. The problem is that after the button click, GUI freezes until the task is completed(here 5 seconds). Is there any way to overcome this ?

```
import sys
import time

try:
    from PySide import QtCore
    from PySide import QtGui
except ImportError:
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
    from PyQt4 import QtGui


class DemoBtn(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DemoBtn, self).__init__()

        x, y, w, h = 500, 400, 400, 200
        self.setGeometry(x, y, w, h)

        x, y, w, h = 30, 10, 96, 32
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Push button", self)
        self.pbar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        btn.setGeometry(x, y, w, h)
        btn.clicked.connect(self._btn_cb)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 50, 200, 25)


    def _btn_cb(self):
        self.pbar.setMaximum(0)
        self.pbar.setMinimum(0)
        time.sleep(5) # some time consuming task here

        print "clicked"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = DemoBtn()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edit 1:**

It seems like the problem is only with the indefinite progressbar (busy progressbar).

Comment: Your call to time.sleep(5) is blocking the main thread which handles the GUI. You should create a worker thread for your time consuming task and use signals/slots to update the progress bar

Comment: @user3419537 That is a common solution, but how do i exchange complex objects with my worker thread and gui thread?

Comment: I have created a worker in this app but unable to exchange comple objects. https://github.com/TheOssGroupForce/pytubedowner/blob/master/app2.py

Comment: You can use custom signals/slots to exchange more complex objects between the threads too. I think the only condition is that you must use "new-style" classes http://stackoverflow.com/a/11278687/3419537